# Diverting spring logs to specific log file using log4j

Tags: log4j

I have the following log4j configuration which works in that it produces two log files, one with the diverted SPRING logs and one where I am attempting to filter out the SPRING content so it is just log messages I have configured using the Logger:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="DEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:/debug/debug.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %C.%M() - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="SPRING" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:/spring/spring.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %C.%M() - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SPRING"/>
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SPRING"/>
    </logger>   
    

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SPRING"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

The problem I am having is that there are still some org.springframework.jdbc calls coming through to my debug log that I am expecting to get diverted to the SPRING log file.

```
2020-06-26 10:05:29,601 DEBUG [scheduling-1] org.springframework.jdbc.object.SqlCall.compileInternal() - Compiled stored procedure. Call string is [{call SQL(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]
2020-06-26 10:05:29,601 DEBUG [scheduling-1] org.springframework.jdbc.object.RdbmsOperation.compile() - RdbmsOperation with SQL [SQL] compiled
```

I tried adding another logger with no success:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="SPRING"/>
    </logger>
```

Any ideas why it isn't getting picked up by these loggers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using log4j2 you can use below format. Please have a look at [log4j](https://www.java2novice.com/spring/logging-with-log4j/) and log4j2 [spring-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2) and [Spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-custom-log-groups) for references.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

    <Properties>
        <!-- process ID -->
        <Property name="PID">????</Property>
        <!-- Log exception conversion -->
        <Property name="LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD">%xwEx</Property>
        <!-- log level pattern -->
        <Property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN">%5p</Property>
        <!-- log date format -->
        <Property name="LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</Property>
        <!-- Final console log pattern -->
        <Property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN">%clr{%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}}}{faint} %clr{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}</Property>
        <!-- Final file log pattern -->
        <Property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN">%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN} ${sys:PID} --- [%t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}</Property>

    </Properties>
    
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console Appender -->
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${sys:CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        
        <!-- File Appender -->
        <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${sys:LOG_FILE}" filePattern="${sys:LOG_PATH}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${sys:FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    
    <!-- Different loggers -->
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version" level="warn" />
        <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="warn"/> <!-- pre-defined -->
        <logger name="org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web" level="warn"/>
        <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core" level="warn"/> <!-- pre-defined -->
        <!-- Root configuration (Console/File) -->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
    
</Configuration>
```

If it's still not working, Please check required logs are enabled or not. (to make sure they are not disabled from any configuration)
**Note:** If you are [using spring-boot](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/spring-boot-log4j2-config/), Spring boot’s default logging uses Logback which is included as transitive dependency.